# Does a shared folder occupy storage space on all accounts?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

If a user shares a Google Drive folder with you, does that shared folder count against your own storage quota?

For example,

1. **userA** creates a folder whose total size is 200MB.
2. This folder counts against **userA**'s available storage, which is now reduced by 200MB.
3. **userA** then shares this folder with **userB** and **userC**.

Is the 200MB only counted against **userA**'s account (folder owner), or is it also counted against the account's of **userB** and **userC**?

Comment: I posted an answer to a question from 2010, including information that might be relevant to this question. At the time that this question was posted, Google Drive allowed files and folders to have multiple-locations, this makes it difficult to answer questions like this due to the possible scenarios. Since 2022 multiple-location files and folders were migrated to file and folder shortcuts.  Since the answers focused on file ownership, it might not be necessary to edit them unless this becomes a canonical question. cc @BlindSpots.

Answer (score 18):

No, the file will only take up space in the owner's account.

Here are the file details from a file that was shared with me in Google Drive.

[image: Shared file in Google Drive, as seen by the share recipient]

Answer (score 17):

The owner account appears to be the one who uploaded the file.  In other words, if a folder is shared by someone else, giving you read/write access to the folder, but you upload a 2GB file to it, then the 2GB file is owned by you and goes against your storage limit; not the storage limit of the folder owner.

Comment: It is possible to transer file ownership, after that the storage will be calculated from the new owner's limit.